# Codeigniter Real Time Notifications under Shared Hosting

Tags: php, node.js, codeigniter

I have tried to google but all i find related to these topics are nodejs and socket.io

which is fine. but problem i am facing is `nodejs` does not work in shared hosting.

I want to know any way i can have real time notifications in Codeigniter while i can still use shared hosting services.
I Don't have much budget to go for VPS. i want to do it for learning purposes right now.

I have seen [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) but still could not find any documentation for it to use with Codeigniter.

-=-=-=-=-=

**UPDATE :**

I don't know how, but someone made it possible to use nodejs on shared hosting with PHP.. 
I have not yet tried it, but gonna try it now :)

feels promising as there is a demo too of it.

Kinda of a library.
https://github.com/niutech/node.php

Demo Link:
http://juvenia.info/node_modules/jt-js-sample/

Comment: You could use one of the other methods people have been using for a while. e.g.. Long Polling

Comment: 1.4k Rep and you ask a question of this quality, you might want to take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) again.

Comment: i didn't try this but it looks not that bad 
take a look @ https://github.com/kishor10d/CodeIgniter-Ratchet-Websocket

Comment: try this one for logic https://gonzalo123.com/2011/05/23/real-time-notifications-part-ii-now-with-node-js-and-socket-io/

Comment: @sintakonte. thankyou.. will look in to it now.

Comment: @AvinashSinha
already have tried nodejs. its great.. but unfortunately i want to try for shared hosting some way. But only for learning, Already know NodeJS and socketing is the real deal. Only want to know if only using socketing is possible in shared hosting for real time notifications.

Comment: @sintakonte
I tried it. but didnt worked, even opened an issue to ask from developer. and also tried his response but no success :(

Comment: http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery long polling is a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar to know for a project,
I found a simple solution: Ajax (Jquery Ajax).
You can make ajax requests at regular interval.

A specific scenario would be notification of messages in inbox.
Right now, i have 2 new messages in my inbox.
Every 4 seconds, i make an ajax call. There i check if there is a new message. If yes, it would be 3 new messages. I return two values: number of messages, isChanged.

Using jquery, if isChanged is true, i update the html, else, i do nothing.

This is just a simple scenario to show you how ajax can be used for notifications.

Comment: But that is just faked real time

Comment: Yes, it is not real time, but it is a possible solution (near real time). Shared hostings are really limited.